'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
I am uploading excel files to GCP bucket and then I want the preview of data. See the image for my test data
def getPreviewDataFromExcel(blob):
    try:
        # Download the file as bytes
        excel_file_stream = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_bytes())
        
        # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame with all columns as strings
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_stream, dtype=str, na_filter=False)

        # Ensure all values in the DataFrame are strings
        for col in df.columns:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

        # Check if the DataFrame is empty
        if df.empty:
            raise ValueError("The uploaded Excel file is empty.")

        # Return the first 25 rows as a list of dictionaries
        return df.head(25).to_dict(orient="records")
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f"ValueError: {ve}")
        raise ve
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while processing the Excel file: {e}")
        raise e

it works fine till I use .to_dict(orient="records"). I just need first 25 rows of file

It might be something related to the contents of the file, we would need sample input and output to reproduce the issue and possibly come up with fix. Also share the error that you got.

The error message (shown in your question) is clear, you cannot compare a datetime type to a string of characters. What is not clear, is where in your code this occurs.

I think OP mentioned the error occurs at .to_dict(orient="records")

If you just want to view the data, you can possibly convert everything to string and see if it works? something like df = df.astype(str)

This is the error I got - '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

When I use .to_dict(orient="records") I am getting above error

I have tried something similar and it works correctly. Please could you edit your question and show a printout of the first few records of your dataframe?
